# ActionbarSherlock action bar custom style

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget, actionbarsherlock

I am developing **Android 2.1 API 7** app. To implement **action bar**, I am using [ActionbarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) library.

I have successfully imported sherlock library to my project, and created the action bar in my app. Then, I would like to customize the style of sherlock action bar. So, I defined the following style file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Sherlock">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_bar_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**But I got error :**

```
No resource found that matches the given name "android:style/Theme.Sherlock"
```

Why? and how can I style sherlock Action bar ??

Comment: I think android:style/Theme.Sherlock its not inside Android jar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Theme.Sherlock` is not in the Android namespace. Simply remove the `android:` prefix and that will resolve your error.

If you're using version 3, there is a styled sample in the `samples/` folder which gives you an example of how to properly style the action bar:

[image]

Comment: I add my custom theme to Activity, it styles the whole screen instead of action bar...